# CD/DVD issue - Can't play music, can't play DVD

Tags: dvd, cd

I know this has been explored, but previous solutions have been tried to no avail.

Hardware note:  CD/DVD works under Windows 7, 8 and 10. Verified: Windows 10 on this exact PC - CD/DVD works.  Install Ubuntu on this exact computer - CD/DVD does NOT work.  Return to windows 10 - CD/DVD WORKS, no issues.

Audio CD:

- Commercially produced, original audio CD (not a copy) provides "Audio CD" icon, spins up, pauses, spins down and tries again and again.  Finally errors to "Unable to access "Audio Disk."  Drive /dev/sr0 does not contain audio files"

[CD Shown In Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l9MG.png)
[The error as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPbCR.png)

DVD:

- Commercially produced, original audio CD (not a copy).  Generates DVD icon. DVD Files appear in file explorer:

[DVD Files Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4fbe.png)

Video files do not play:

[Video Not Playing and Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVCLX.png)

Tried this:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

$ sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
'multiverse' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.

$ sudo apt install libdvd-pkg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libdvd-pkg is already the newest version (1.4.2-1-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1 libllvm9 python3-click python3-colorama
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.

$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
libdvd-pkg: guest package [libdvdcss2/1.4.2-1~local] is already installed.
```

The System:

```
$ inxi -F

System:
  Host: scott-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC Kernel: 5.4.0-48-generic x86_64 
  bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 

Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP Pavilion g6 Notebook PC 
  v: 0889110002305910000620100 serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 1849 v: 57.34 
  serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: Insyde v: F.23 date: 11/22/2012 

Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 41.1 Wh condition: 41.1/41.1 Wh (100%) 

CPU:
  Topology: Quad Core model: AMD A8-4500M APU with Radeon HD Graphics 
  bits: 64 type: MCP L2 cache: 2048 KiB 
  Speed: 1354 MHz min/max: 1400/1900 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1356 2: 1362 
  3: 1321 4: 1344 

Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Trinity [Radeon HD 7640G] driver: radeon v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: radeon resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD ARUBA (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.4.0-48-generic LLVM 10.0.0) 
  v: 4.3 Mesa 20.0.8 

Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Trinity HDMI Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: AMD FCH Azalia driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-3: GN Netcom HP TrueVision HD type: USB 
  driver: jabra,snd-usb-audio,usbhid 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-48-generic 

Network:
  Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter driver: ath9k 
  IF: wlo1 state: down mac: 20:16:d8:0a:6d:75 
  Device-2: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet driver: r8169 
  IF: eno1 state: down mac: 84:34:97:86:b8:c9 
  Device-3: Ralink RT5372 Wireless Adapter type: USB driver: rt2800usb 
  IF: wlx9cefd5fc9c02 state: up mac: 9c:ef:d5:fc:9c:02 

Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 585.01 GiB used: 66.04 GiB (11.3%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Samsung model: SSD 860 EVO 500GB size: 465.76 GiB 
  ID-2: /dev/sdb type: USB vendor: SanDisk model: Cruzer Glide 
  size: 119.25 GiB 

Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 456.96 GiB used: 39.11 GiB (8.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 

Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 63.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: radeon temp: 61 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 

Info:
  Processes: 204 Uptime: 1h 59m Memory: 7.25 GiB used: 848.0 MiB (11.4%) 
  Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!!